# Got .PNG file. Want embeddded icon resource displayed as icon on form title bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This was an interview question. Given Visual Studio 2008 and an icon saved as a .PNG file, they required the image as an embedded resource and to be used as the icon within the title bar of a form.

I'm looking for what would have been the model answer to this question, Both (working!) code and any Visual Studio tricks. (Model answer is one that should get me the job if I meet it next time around.)

Specifically I don't know how to load the image once it is an embedded resource nor how to get it as the icon for the title bar.

As a part solution, ignoring the embedded bit, I copied the resource to the ouput directory and tried the following:-

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Icon = new Icon("Resources\\IconImage.png");
    }
}
```

This failed with the error "Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon."

I presuming that the .PNG file actually needed to be a .ICO, but I couldn't see how to make the conversion. Is this presumption correct or is there a different issue?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Fire up VS, start new Windows Application. Open the properties sheet, add the .png file as a resource (in this example: glider.png ). From hereon, you can access the resource as a Bitmap file as WindowsFormsApplication10.Properties.Resources.glider

Code for using it as an application icon:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Bitmap bmp = WindowsFormsApplication10.Properties.Resources.glider;
            this.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon());
        }
```

Comment: I had to do full name space System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle( but works great thank you

Comment: `
Bitmap bitmap = new("xxx.png");
this.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());

`

-- this works with .Net 8.0 (make sure "Copy Always")

Answer (score 26):

`Icon.FromHandle` will cause problems with a PNG, because PNGs have more than one bit of transparency. This type of issue can be solved with a library like [IconLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx).

Chances are they didn't know how to do it and they were trying to squeeze the answer out of potential employees. Furthermore, setting the icon of the form from a PNG is an unnecessary performance hit, it should have been an ICO in the first place.

Comment: "Icon.FromHandle will cause problems with a PNG, because PNGs have more than one bit of transparency." - demonstrating this knowledge would offer valuable insight to an interviewer that the developer has likely dealt with real world applications and shipping application issues.

Comment: Good answer. I'll remember this answer in case I will be asked dumb questions in interviews.

Comment: @Icon.FromHandle "will cause problems with a PNG" - what kind of problems?

Comment: @user626528 - the pixels in the PNG that are totally transparent _might_ actually turn out transparent in the ICON, but the pixels that are **partially** transparent will be totally opaque in the ICON. E.g., it will look ugly.

Comment: Downvoted simply because the answer is antagonistic. No need for snark, just answer the question.

Answer (score 18):

Go here:

http://www.getpaint.net/ (free)

And here:

[Paint.NET ico Plugin](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/927-icon-cursor-and-animated-cursor-format-v37-may-2010/) (free)

Install Paint.NET. Put the ico plugin (second link) into the Paint.NET\FileTypes folder. Start up Paint.NET. Open your .png and save it as an .ico.

Free and easy.

Comment: Although this is not the model answer, it is certainly a **very** helpful set of links!

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz, the second link is dead too.

Answer (score 1):

A good resource on the subject in *[C# 2.0 Convert Bitmap to Icon](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4a10d440-707f-48d7-865b-1d8804faf649/)*.

Comment: Nice routine for converting an image to an icon. In my case image had right dimensions for an icon so maybe a simplification is possible?

Also I don't have a way of getting at the embedded image.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my purposes since all of my resources were PNG files:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

// From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.gethicon.aspx
private Icon bitmapToIcon(Bitmap myBitmap)
{
    // Get an Hicon for myBitmap.
    IntPtr Hicon = myBitmap.GetHicon();

    // Create a new icon from the handle.
    Icon newIcon = Icon.FromHandle(Hicon);

    return newIcon;
}
```

Comment: You declared, but did not call, `DestroyIcon( Hicon );` It will need to be called at some point.  The code you cite recommends copying the Icon, then calling `DestroyHandle(newIcon.Handle);`