# How to programatically (or via VS) set program Icon in non-ico format

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I have a set of icons in PNG. I was able to load them into my project under Resources>Icons and I select other than ICO format. The problem is I cannot assign it to the forms since its non ICO. I tried some conversions but I was not succesful. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this related question: [Got .PNG file. Want embeddded icon resource displayed as icon on form title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154119/got-png-file-want-embeddded-icon-resource-displayed-as-icon-on-form-title-bar)