# Create a shortcut with a png icon in C#

Tags: c#, .net, icons, shortcut

I have a .net application that can create lnk shortcuts on the desktop for various purposes (let's say application A creates a shortcut for application B). These shortcuts are **independent** from this application and I would like to be able to programmatically add an custom icon to this shortcut (the shortcut for application B uses a custom icon not present in A or in B).

I already know how to do with an icon indexed in a dll or a .exe with the WSH library (this is described for example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce3ba993-2578-48b5-acb4-5421af950b05/how-to-change-the-icon-for-a-shortcut-on-the-desktop-in-c-20?forum=csharpgeneral)) but what I want to do is to use a custom .png file.

Has anyone already did this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got .PNG file. Want embeddded icon resource displayed as icon on form title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154119/got-png-file-want-embeddded-icon-resource-displayed-as-icon-on-form-title-bar)

Comment: How do you create shortcut? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893182/1997232) a way to specify icon.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, I edited the initial post. This has nothing to do with the icon of a form (but the icon of a lnk shortcut which is a created file), or with an indexed icon in a dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:
[Path to an embedded resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283313/path-to-an-embedded-resource-file#answer-12612984)
IconLocation works also for external files.